# Stop test & mark as completed (during Test)

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm looking for a way for CUI-Tests to stop a test through a command, however return that the test was completed successfully.
For Example:

```
if (something)
{
   //Code
}
else
{
   //Test should be aborted here; but marked as Completed
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm looking for a way to do this.

Comment: using autodesk(autocad) ?

Comment: @zackraiyan using Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise).

Comment: lolz i meant if u r using autocad's api

Comment: @zackraiyan No.

Answer (score 1):

One simple mechanism is to move the body of the test method into a helper method and have the main test method call that helper. Whenever the test needs to exit and have the test pass just do a `return`. The code would look something like the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{
    CodedUITestMethod1Helper();
}

public void CodedUITestMethod1Helper()
{
    ... some test code ...;

    if (something)
    {
       ... more test code ...;
    }
    else
    {
       // Test is aborted here; but marked as Completed
       return;
    }

    ... some test code ...;

    if (something else)
    {
       ... more test code ...;
    }
    else
    {
       // Test is aborted here; but marked as Completed
       return;
    }

    ... some test code ...;
}
```